# INSERT trigger which with the INSERT statements within

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, insert

In some cases when a record is inserted into a table, it should be split into few records, which would be inserted instead.

The logic is written inside an INSERT trigger, which fires before the INSERT operation. Inside of this trigger I am trying to execute an INSERT statement, which subsequently causes a recursive call of the trigger. However I do not want this to happen. I tried to disable a trigger from its body using smth like

`execute immediate 'ALTER TRIGGER sale_trigger DISABLE';`

But, obviously it is a commit operation and thus it doesnt work from inside of the trigger.

How can I get around this recursive call of the trigger?

**Edit** I declared my trigger as this `declare PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;` and now i can run `alter` statement. However when I disable a trigger from the same trigger - the PLSQL developer stops working. What do I do? :)

Comment: Maybe there is a way, how you can understand that the trigger is being called the second time, for example, from data begin inserted? So you can check this directly in trigger and won't call insert in case of the second call.

Comment: Havent found a way to distiguish whether the trigger is being called the first time. Analyzing the data doesnt seem to help in my case

Comment: Only workaround i've managed to find is an additional column in the target table with some default value, which will differ for values being inserted via trigger, so trigger will check it and won't do insert, if it differs from default value. Seems not good, though, especially, if you can't change datastructure...

Comment: True. I've been adviced to move all the logic from the trigger into a separate procedure, which is I would probably do

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading the first insert directly into your target table, insert records into a staging table. The trigger with the troublesome logic should be on the staging table. If the logic does not apply, the trigger inserts the row into the target table. If the logic applies, the trigger inserts the row (if necessary?) and fires off whatever additional inserts to the target table are required. Truncate the staging table on regular intervals to keep it small and efficient (but probably not after each trigger operation since this would be less efficient).

In other words: decouple the trigger from the table it is inserting into.